# Server side virus scan on a file for Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, antivirus

I need to scan uploaded files on a windows server through my ASP.NET web app. 
However, am not aware if anti virus packages come with an "api" sort of a thing using which i can programmatically trigger the scan.
If possible i would really want to avoid any kind of windows scheduling to trigger the antivirus and then report the errors.

Answer (score 4):

[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/) offers API support and is free. I am also sure that many other commercial vendors offer the same at a price (generally large).

http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/html/node32.html

Note: you will need to access the functionalities through P/Invokes.

Comment: It appears they've stopped development of ClamAV for Win32. Check this out http://w32.clamav.net/
Is ClamAV my only option? My client wud be happier to hear a more popular AV taking care of their server.