# Virus scanning component

Tags: c#, asp.net, components

I need to scan uploaded files on the server side. 
I have asp.net application. The application is hosted on Windows server. 
Can you point to some component or even commercial product with SDK or API, that can do the scan?

Comment: After researching a bit more, may be i will go with MetaScan. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

[Server side virus scan on a file for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264891/server-side-virus-scan-on-a-file-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at [ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/) which is the windows portage of [clamav](http://www.clamav.com/) antivirus on *nix. You'll be able to use the provided library or to use the command line tools to wrap the scan.

Comment: http://clamav-sharp.sourceforge.net/ helps run the ClamAV daemon on your server.