# How to do a virus scan before post attachments in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, virus-scanning

How to do a virus scan before post attachments in **asp.net application**,when they find a virus on to give up post attachments,otherwise proceed to upload.

Comment: Did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264891/server-side-virus-scan-on-a-file-for-windows ? Is server side but I doubt whether it is possible in client side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You scan it at the server, and delete it if it doesn't pass. There's no way to know if the client side has any AV software installed at all, and any result you got could be faked anyway. Do your checking on the server side instead where you have control.